# inner json array cannot be accessed in javascript, but can console log the complete json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-cloud-vision

`console.log(e.responseText);
  testNature(e.responseText.responses[0]);`

I cannot use the inner array of a JSON response it says:-

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

when I console log the e.responseText I get:-

```
 {
  "responses": [
    {
      "labelAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/06mb1",
          "description": "rain",
          "score": 0.930509,
          "topicality": 0.930509
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/0838f",
          "description": "water",
          "score": 0.91255623,
          "topicality": 0.91255623
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01ctsf",
          "description": "atmosphere",
          "score": 0.86684966,
          "topicality": 0.86684966
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/04k84",
          "description": "light",
          "score": 0.8194458,
          "topicality": 0.8194458
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01bqvp",
          "description": "sky",
          "score": 0.7569251,
          "topicality": 0.7569251
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but cannot use the inner array `e.responseText.responses[0]` to call a function ie testNature(e.responseText.responses[0]) . I got the JSON from google cloud vision API

Comment: Did u try JSON.parse() on the string responseText before it is being handled like an object?

Comment: What you see when `console.log(typeof(e.responseText))`?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. when I console logged I got it as String so I parsed it and now the issue solved. thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short version

Convert the string to object using:

```
responseText = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

#### Explanation

```
e.responseText.responses[0]
```

gives error - Cannot read property 0 of undefined

Means `e.responseText.responses` is undefined.

Means `e.responseText` don't have a defined property `responses`

Means `e.responseText` is not the object we are looking for.

In this context, It Means type of `e.responseText` is likely string

To confirm, log the data type of the same using:

```
console.log(typeof(e.responseText))
```

if this gives output `string`, convert the same to an object using `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is likely a result of a `responseText` object that does not contain a `responses` property. The example you provided works.

```js
const e = {
  "responseText": {
    "responses": [
      {
        "labelAnnotations": [
          {
            "mid": "/m/06mb1",
            "description": "rain",
            "score": 0.930509,
            "topicality": 0.930509
          },
          {
            "mid": "/m/0838f",
            "description": "water",
            "score": 0.91255623,
            "topicality": 0.91255623
          },
          {
            "mid": "/m/01ctsf",
            "description": "atmosphere",
            "score": 0.86684966,
            "topicality": 0.86684966
          },
          {
            "mid": "/m/04k84",
            "description": "light",
            "score": 0.8194458,
            "topicality": 0.8194458
          },
          {
            "mid": "/m/01bqvp",
            "description": "sky",
            "score": 0.7569251,
            "topicality": 0.7569251
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

const testNature = o => { console.log(o); }

testNature(e.responseText.responses[0]);
```